# Is this error from Qt or my program?

Tags: c++, qt5, valgrind

I'm new to valgrind. I have written a program in C++ using Qt 5.5.1 libraries on Ubuntu 15.10. I'm using Qt Creator with Debug build set. I checked for memory leaks using Valgrind with the following command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./texteditor
```

Valgrind then gives me the following message:

```
==2977== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2977==    at 0x97ED1EC: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.28)
==2977==    by 0x97EE58A: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.28)
==2977==    by 0x5B3380B: g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__VOID (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==2977==    by 0x5B31B8A: g_closure_invoke (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==2977==    by 0x5B43FFB: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==2977==    by 0x5B4CC95: g_signal_emit_valist (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==2977==    by 0x5B4CFC4: g_signal_emit (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==2977==    by 0x96ECD00: gtk_adjustment_changed (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.28)
==2977==    by 0x5B35465: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==2977==    by 0x5B384FC: g_object_thaw_notify (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4600.2)
==2977==    by 0x96ED182: gtk_adjustment_configure (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.28)
==2977==    by 0x4563C7F: ??? (in /home/tembo/Qt/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.1)
==2977==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2977==    at 0x456215F: ??? (in /home/tembo/Qt/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.1)
```

From the above message nothing points to the location of myProgram at all. Is this from Qt and other libraries or do I miss something pointing to myProgram?

Comment: Try to compile your program with debug information (`-g -O0`) and run `valgrind` again.

Comment: @Drop, I'm using Qt Creator to compile and have set to Debug build, does -g defer from Debug build?

Comment: You'd need to compile Qt itself with debug information... (`-debug` switch to configure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Valgrind only shows the top 12 entries of the call stack, but this can be changed with the `--num-callers=xx` parameter. The functions from your own program code are likely further down on the stack.

Comment: Note also that a debug build (as per comments) will also tend to increase the call stack requirements as functions will not be inlined.